# How do I access my ether from my unencrypted private keys?

Tags: ether, private-key, jaxx

I previously used Jaxx, where I stored some Ether. I have now uninstalled Jaxx, but would like to access my Ether in any way possible.

I don't have the Jaxx mnemonic as it was never made clear that I needed it, but luckily I do have my private key and public address, both of which Jaxx provides in unencrypted form.

I have tried the 'import paper wallet' tool in a new Jaxx wallet, but it just says 'scanning private key' for an hour and doesn't do anything. I have also tried importing via geth, but for some reason my balance shows up as 0. This might be because geth was linked to a testnet?

Any help with retrieving my ethereum is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/) is able to do this.  It can access an account based on the private key only, e.g. the "Send Ether & Tokens" or the "View Wallet Info" tabs. Select "Private Key" as the access method. It is off-line and safe if used according the the instructions - you can download the code from GitHub and run it locally if you are extra-cautious.

Just, please, please, be sure to go to the correct site!  Look for the EVSSL banner in the browser bar:

[image]

Comment: According to MEW website, it would seem that this prectice is prohibited within the MEW wallet ( https://kb.myetherwallet.com/en/mewwallet/mewwallet-private-key/ ) I too am looking for a simple way to access my Ether. Any other solutions available ?